# What does "put on" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I'm watching "Fear And Loathing In Las Vegas" and there is a sentence I don't understand. The context is hard to provide because the sentence is one of the main character's random visions while being very high on some strange drug called Adrenochrome.

One person in his visions says: "you can't **put on** a circus without a tent"

Does "put on" in this context mean:
organize or present a play, exhibition, or event.

> "the museum is putting on an exhibition of Monet's paintings"(source thefreedictionary)

Comment: Yes, you have found the correct definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. 'organize' *is* what this would mean in this context.